# Centering Scale Command value on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to move the numeric value **0.0** to the center of the `Scale` command from `tkinter` package.
I tried to anchor and justify it, but I get the following error:`unknown option "-anchor"` or `unknown option "-justify"`. Please see the image for a visual example.

Edit:
I am trying to keep the *0.0* value in the center of the scale.

[image]

I took the liberty to simplify the code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')

exampleScale = Scale(root, resolution=0.1, from_=0, to=1, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                     width=250, length=550)
exampleScale.config(font=('Times', 32))
exampleScale.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tecnique uses setting of `sliderlength` parameter of `Scale` to double times of font size value :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')

fsize=32
exampleScale = Scale(root, sliderlength=fsize*2, resolution=0.1, from_=0, to=1,
                     orient=HORIZONTAL, width=250, length=550)
exampleScale.config(font=('Times', fsize))
exampleScale.grid(row=1,column=1)


root.mainloop()
```